# Change a Facebook 'page owner' (not admin)

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I am a page admin along with a few others. There is now a 'Page Owner' listed on top, and it's a company. I'm assuming this is a business account? How can this page owner be changed? Who has the rights?

[image: Page roles list entry: "Company Inc. (Page Owner) Admins of the Embrace Entertainment Inc. business can manage roles and other permissions on this Page."]

Answer (score 3):

Only the Page Admin have the rights to change the page owner. There are no specific information on how to change the ownership in that page however you can transfer the page ownership from one account to another.

[What are the different Page roles and what can they do?](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/289207354498410)

To check your role on the page Click **Settings** at the top of your Page > **Page Roles** in the left column.

If you want to transfer your **Facebook PAGE** to another person or account (who must have a Facebook profile) you need to ensure that they are your Facebook **Friend** or have **Liked** your PAGE.

Go to your PAGE to manage the **Admins** > click **Edit Page** > **Admin Roles**. And start typing **name** so it appears and click on the profile to place it in the box, and then click **Save Changes**.

If the name method doesn't work, try entering their email address in the box as that often works.

And if that doesn't work try below, as sometimes there is a glitch doing it the "correct" way.

Click > **Edit Page** > and R**IGHT-CLICK** on **"See Banned Users"** and "**Open in New Tab / Window**". When the page arrives change **"Banned"** to **"People who like this"**, then find the person there on the list and click **"Make Admin"**. ALSO if there are any other **BLANK** boxes below, then click the **"x"** next to them and remove them, then do the **"Save"** and add your password, which is the Admin's own personal Facebook login password. You might have to try it several times to make it work.

If you make that new Admin a "**Manager**" they will now have as much control of your PAGE as yourself. (If you are asked for a password use your own personal Facebook login password).

If you want to relinquish your Admin status, just click "**Remove Admin**" against your name, and if you wish to leave the PAGE completely, just view the PAGE and click "**Unlike**".

Answer (score 0):

How to transfer Facebook Page Owner "Facebook Business Manager"

1. Be sure there is a second Administrator of the page!!!
2. In YOUR Business Manager there is few tabs in the main menu that you need to look at:
   2.a The tab PEOPLE

   - Normally this is you or your personal Facebook Business Manager.
   - Go and remove your self by clicking the X in the right corner of the desired page.
   - Don't add other people in your Business Manager if you don't know what are you doing just make sure they like the Page or they are already with Administrator role.
     2.b The tab PAGES
   - When you click on the desired page ( when you have multiply pages ), you will see a big button "REMOVE" even if you see yourself in the "Assigned People" tab just click remove on the right corner in the current page details.
   - In case the page you want to remove is your Primary Business Page you can change this form the "Info" tab on the very bottom of the Main menu.
3. If you skip point ( 2.a ) you will have the admin rights in the Page not in Business Manager.
4. More or less you are free now ;) but if you still has Access as Admin just go and remove your self from the Page setting ( Removing from Business manager is just removing the control inside the Business manager )
5. Page Owner that look very seriously Awesome!!! but it doesn't do anything, this are my observations.

Answer (score -1):

The person who owns that company I assume also is an admin of that page. Let them login to business.facebook.com to make the necessary change.