# Change page OWNER (not admin) on Facebook

Tags: facebook

A former employee had designated herself as the page OWNER of our company Facebook page. I'm still listed as an admin, as is one other person, but I can't remove this former employee as the page owner.

How do I transfer ownership of the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change a Facebook 'page owner' (not admin)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75299/change-a-facebook-page-owner-not-admin)